# Kafka Connect Custom Transformation : Override of apply() method seems to have no effect, but overriding newRecord method in key and value works

Tags: apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create a custom connector following the pattern used in the samples

> https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ExtractField.java
>
> https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-insert-uuid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/cjmatta/kafka/connect/smt/InsertUuid.java

I have overriden the apply method to add a small string to the payload

```
    public R apply(R record) {
        log.info("Transformation apply has started...");
        String newValue = record.value().toString() + " this has been transformed" ;
        log.info("Message changed to : " + newValue);
        return newRecord(record, null, newValue);
    }
```

This has no effect at all. The output is not changed. I also do not see the log info messages anywhere in the generated log.

However if I override the newRecord method of the Value class I am able to see the message being updated. Also i see the info messages being logged.

```
        protected R newRecord(R record, Schema updatedSchema, Object updatedValue) {
            log.info("Message Value being changed to :");
            return record.newRecord(record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(), record.keySchema(), record.key(),
 updatedSchema, "This is updated : " + updatedValue.toString(), record.timestamp());
        }
```

This results in the output message being updated as expected. Note that the payload in the message is a string payload and does not have any particular structure.

I was thinking that this payload manipulation can occur in apply() method as well. Also I do not see this apply() method being called in the transformation run. The payload is not affected and the messages are not logged.

Am I missing something here. Is the apply() method being called or used incorrectly. Any guidance is appreciated.

Note : Overriding the newRecord method of the key class also works.

The full source code of the transformation is below

```
package com.xxxxx.yyyyy.kafka.connect.transform;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.ConnectRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Transformation;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Map;

public abstract class SampleTransform<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleTransform.class);
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {

    }

    @Override
    public R apply(R record) {
        log.info("Transformation apply has started...");        //This does not work
        String newValue = record.value().toString() + " this has been transformed" ;
        log.info("Message changed to : " + newValue);
        return newRecord(record, null, "Message is fully changed");     //Output does not change
    }

    protected abstract Schema operatingSchema(R record);

    protected abstract Object operatingValue(R record);

    protected abstract R newRecord(R record, Schema updatedSchema, Object updatedValue);

    public static class Key<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> extends HoistField<R> {
        @Override
        protected Schema operatingSchema(R record) {
            return record.keySchema();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object operatingValue(R record) {
            return record.key();
        }

        @Override
        protected R newRecord(R record, Schema updatedSchema, Object updatedValue) {
            log.info("Key being changed to : " + updatedValue.toString());          //This is logged
            return record.newRecord(record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(), updatedSchema, updatedValue, record.valueSchema(), record.value(), record.timestamp());
        }
    }

    public static class Value<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> extends HoistField<R> {
        @Override
        protected Schema operatingSchema(R record) {
            return record.valueSchema();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object operatingValue(R record) {
            return record.value();
        }

        @Override
        protected R newRecord(R record, Schema updatedSchema, Object updatedValue) {
            log.info("Message Value being changed to :");               // This is logged
            return record.newRecord(record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(), record.keySchema(), record.key(), updatedSchema, "This is updated : " + updatedValue.toString(), record.timestamp());          //This works
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your `Transfomation` implementation.

Comment: Added the transformation implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that you extends `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField` instead of your *Transformation* - **`SampleTransform`**

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked. extends HoistField<R> was the mistake.